# Restrict negative lookahead to be between substrings regex

Tags: python, regex

In my regex pattern, I would like to make sure a certain substring only occurs once in between two other substrings.

So, let's take for example these strings:

```
string_a = “this and that”
string_b = "this and and that"
```

I want to return a match for string_a but not for string_b, because 'and' occurs twice there between this/that.
I would do that with a negative lookahead-tempered dot:

```
my_pattern = "this(?:(?!and.*and).)*that"
```

This matches string_a and not string_b, so so far so good.

However, with the following sentence is also not matched (like string_b):

```
string_c = "this and that and"
```

Evidently, the negative lookahead occurs for the whole string, rather than between "this" and "that" as I had anticipated and hoped.

How can I do this instead?

Comment: Then add `that` restriction, `my_pattern = "this(?:(?!and(?:(?!that).)*?and).)*that"`. You probably also need to add the boundary restrictions, ``my_pattern = "this(?:(?!this|taht|and(?:(?!that).)*?and).)*?that"``

Comment: A more generic example using word matching instead of dot matching would be `this(?: (?!(\w+\b) \1\b)\w+)* that` which does not allow any word to be repeated between "this" and "that".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use another tempered greedy token to temper the `.*` inside the lookahead:

```
this(?:(?!this|that|and(?:(?!that).)*?and).)*?that
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zn8bip/2).

*Details*:

- `this` - a fixed string
- `(?:(?!this|that|and(?:(?!that).)*?and).)*?` - any char other than line break chars, zero or more but as few as possible occurrernces, that does not start a `this`, `that` char sequences or a pattern that matches `and`, then  any char other than line break chars, zero or more but as few as possible occurrernces, that does not start a `that` char sequence and then `and` string
- `that` - a fixed string.